# How to use mysql GROUP BY function to get multiple records

Tags: php, mysql, aggregate

I have following table:

```
-----------------------------------------
id | advid | chq_num | chq_date | amount
-----------------------------------------
 1 | 102 | 121212 | 2015-01-01 | 10000
-----------------------------------------
 2 | 102 | 121213 | 2015-01-02 | 8000
-----------------------------------------
 3 | 103 | 121214 | 2015-01-03 | 9000
-----------------------------------------
 4 | 102 | 121215 | 2015-01-04 | 10000
-----------------------------------------
 5 | 103 | 121216 | 2015-01-05 | 7000
-----------------------------------------
```

Now I want to show the following information:

```
Advance ID: 102  Advance Amount: 28000
Cheque Num: 121212, 121213, 121215 Cheque Date: 2015-01-01, 2015-01-02, 2015-01-04
```

For this purpose I have used following query and code:

```
SELECT advid, sum(amount), chq_num, chq_date FROM my_table GROUP BY advid
```

after executing the query from php, while trying to fetch the result:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
echo 'Advance ID:'.$row['advid'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;Advance Amount: '.$row['amount'].'<br />;
echo 'Cheque Num: '.$row['chq_num'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;Cheque Date: '.$row['chq_date']
```

But by the above fetching technique, I can get only first 'Cheque Num' and first 'Cheque Date'. How to fetch in a way so that I can get all the cheque num and cheque date delimited by ',' (comma)?

Comment: `group_concat` is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)** function for this

```
SELECT 
advid, 
sum(amount) as amount, 
group_concat(chq_num) as chq_num, 
group_concat(chq_date) as chq_date
FROM my_table GROUP BY advid
```

The `chq_num` and `chq_date` will be returned as comma separated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT advid,
       group_concat(chq_num),
       sum(amount),
       group_concat(chq_date) 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY advid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of aggregate functions like `sum` and `group_concat` for your desired result.

```
SELECT advid
     , sum(amount) as advance_amount
     , group_concat(chq_num) as cheque_numbers
     , group_concat(chq_date) as cheque_dates
 FROM my_table 
GROUP BY advid
```

**Refer to**:

- [MySQL: GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

  - This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL values from a group. It returns NULL if there are no non-NULL values.